# Knitr chunk is importing a subset of the records from *.csv as same code in R

Tags: r, knitr

Rstudio version 0.96.331 and knitr version 0.8

I thought my problem had been solved with update of RStudio and libraries... however:

The following run in R gives me 940 unique Table.ID values.  Run in a knitr chunk I get 228 unique values and the following warning:

"invalid input found on input connection 'http://www2.census.gov/acs2010_5yr/summaryfile/Sequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.txt'

I don't understand why the distinction exists between the two methods.

```
Sequence <- read.csv("http://www2.census.gov/acs2010_5yr/summaryfile/Sequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.txt",
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
unique(Sequence$Table.ID)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of `rstudio` and `knitr` are you using?

Comment: Please update your question with output from `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Try now with the `fileEncoding` argument (see updated answer below).

Comment: That worked! Thanks.  Now, do you know of any documentation of why the fileEncoding argument must be used in knitr and not in the console?

Comment: @MichaelWilliams That is because RStudio sets `options(encoding = 'UTF-8')` before calling `knitr`. It is probably worth reporting to RStudio developers, or you can reset to default `options(encoding = 'native.enc')` before you read the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine on Rstudio version `0.96.331` and knitr version `0.8`

My `.Rmd` file:

````
        knitr test for length
        ========================================================
        This should successfully return a length of 940

    ```{r}
    Sequence <- read.csv("http://www2.census.gov/acs2010_5yr/summaryfile/Sequence_Number_and_Table_Number_Lookup.txt", 
fileEncoding = "iso8859-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    length(unique(Sequence$Table.ID))
    ```
````

Resulting in this:

[image]

Comment: As you say, setting the `fileEncoding` you give to `read.csv` is the solution.  The value that works for me is `native.enc`, I found it by running `getOption("encoding")` in an interactive session.  `knitr` changes it to `UTF-8`.